# Where to start with scripting project - searching a log-in only web site from term/cmd

Tags: python, search, curl

I'm attempting to write a script for myself that will log in to a specific website and use the website's search function. The script will then write the list of search results to standard output, where I will then select one of the results and do various actions on the page. I'm very lost as where to start with this. I've already attempted cURL and python's various web libraries, but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the web site, and whether that web site wants to prevent this behavior.  Most major sites either actively discourage this or provide APIs to do it relatively easily and securely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that website doesn't provide a search API, you need to do automated scraping, in which case *curl* etc. are way too low-level and error-prone.
Here are are some widely-used recommendations:

For automation, link-following, formfilling etc., I strongly recommend [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) API, which is an automation layer which sits on top of [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). twill has a [bunch of useful extension modules](http://twill.idyll.org/extensions.html).
As just one example, for filling in authentication forms, [twill.formfill multi_sub](http://twill.idyll.org/extensions.html#formfill-convenience-functions-for-filling-out-forms) is great.

For manual scraping, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), but *twill* probably already does what you need (scrapes all the links, forms etc.).